# Display in mvc table days from begin job date

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new with MVC, I have a model with employee properties, one of the properties is `public DateTime BeginJob { get; set; }`. When the user create a new employee he enters the date that the employee started to work in the company.

My question is how can I display in the table that in `index.cshtml` only the number of days from now? where should I make those changes? in the model? controller? view?

Employee (Driver in my case) model:

```
public class Driver
{
   [Key]
    public int LicenceID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    ....
    public DateTime BeginJob { get; set; }
}
```

index.cshtml :

```
@model IEnumerable<try4.Models.Driver>
....

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)</th>
        ....
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BeginJob)</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)</td>
            ....
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BeginJob)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean that "number of days from now"? it is number of days from BeginJob to now?

Comment: Yes, if today is 12/08/2017 and begin job is 10/08/2017 then I want that in the table will be the number 2 @DanNguyen

Comment: Use a `TimeSpan` - `(item.BeginJob - DateTime.Today).TotalDays` (and best to create a view model with a property for the number of days and do the calculation in the controller method (or model)

Comment: Also what would you want to display if the `BeginJob` value is in the past?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't understand your question, begin job is alaweys in the past, i.e the employee started to work two years ago/ one year ago etc

Comment: So you cannot add a new employee before they have actually started? (we enter new employees as soon as they have been contracted even though they may not start immediately)

Comment: @StephenMuecke No, it's not possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151768/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-error-404).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change from

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BeginJob)
```

to

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (DateTime.Now - item.BeginJob).Days)
```